# React: Printing to the console executes after changes, instead of before, as it would be logical

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to print to the console a 2-dimensional array, before doing different changes regarding its values (By pressing certain keys), but the printout displays the result of the changes, even tho that should happen only after the printing.

Is it some kind of lifecycle issue?

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     rows: this.createGrid(props),
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
   document.onkeydown = this.onKeyPressed;
}
onKeyPressed = (e) => {
   let grid = this.state.rows;
   console.table(grid); //PRINTOUT
   let flipped = false;
   let rotated = false;
   e = e || window.event;
   switch (e.keyCode) {
     case 39:
       //RIGHT
       grid = this.doSlide(grid);
       break;
     case 37:
       //LEFT
       grid = this.flip(grid);
       grid = this.doSlide(grid);
       flipped = true;
       break;
     case 40:
       //DOWN
       grid = this.rotate(grid);
       grid = this.doSlide(grid);
       rotated = true;
       break;
     case 38:
       //UP
       grid = this.rotate(grid);
       grid = this.flip(grid);
       grid = this.doSlide(grid);   
       rotated = true;
       flipped = true;
       break;
   }

   if (flipped) {
     grid = this.flip(grid);
   }
   if (rotated) {
     grid = this.rotate(grid);
     grid = this.rotate(grid);
     grid = this.rotate(grid);
   }

   this.setState({ rows: grid });
   this.placeRandom();
 };
```

I am willing to make a copy of the grid before the actions, so that after they can be compared, but the same issue occurs there as well. The already changed grid is copied...

Comment: Note that (at least in Chrome), logging an object to the console is a *live view* of the object, not a snapshot of it at the time of the log call.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @JaredSmith even if I make another variable, in the beginning, I get back the same. How can that variable change also?
Something like:
   let grid = this.state.rows;
    let copiedGrid = this.copyGrid(grid); //copy the grid one by one with 2 for loops
    console.table(copiedGrid);

Comment: Because it's a reference to the same object: `const foo = {}; const bar = foo; foo.a = 3; console.log(bar); // {a: 3};`. You'd have to copy it to have it remained unchanged: `const bar = {...foo};`. Note that's only a shallow copy, you can still have inner references that hold.

Comment: Yeah I assume there is still some kind of inner reference. `let grid = this.state.rows;
    let copiedGrid = {...grid};
    console.table(copiedGrid);` returns the same as before :/

Comment: If `this.state.rows` is an array, and the items in it are objects: `const copied = this.state.rows.map(x => ({...x}));` if it's an object and the values are themselves objects: `const copied = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this.state.rows).map(([key, value]) => [key, {...value}]));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221793/discussion-between-zolly-and-jared-smith).

Answer (score 0):

try with the copy of the state.rows object

```
let grid = {...this.state.rows};
console.table(grid); //PRINTOUT
```